# How to hover marker on MarkerWithLabel Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using MarkerWithLabel on Google map, when Im on mouse over on marker it not show dialog information. It just show when click on marker. I have some css following as:

```
<style>     
.labels {
 margin-top:-3px;
 padding: 5px;
 position: absolute;
visibility: visible;
z-index: 1030;
}
.labels.active .inner {
    background: cyan;
}
.labels.hover .inner {
    background-color: yellow;
}   
.labels .arrow{
    border-top-color: #ff5a5f;
    border-right-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-width: 5px 5px 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
.labels .inner{
    background-color: #ff5a5f;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;  
}   
.labels.active .arrow {     
    border-top-color: #00ffff;
    border-right-color: rgba(0,255,255,0);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0,255,255,0);
    border-left-color: rgba(0,255,255,0);
}
.labels.hover .arrow {
    border-top-color: #ffff00;
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,0,0);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,0,0);
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,0,0);
}
```

and Javascript:

```
    function initMap() {
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.0241852,105.8292388);   
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 16,   /*16*/
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       });

    var cityHightlight;
        //DRAW THE POLYGON OR POLYLINE
        cityHightlight = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: hanois,
        strokeColor: "#F85555",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FFFFFF",
        fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        cityHightlight.setMap(map);

        // create a bounds object
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();                          
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.23333, 105.2325512);                 

        bounds.extend(latLng);                          
            var markerMap = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: latLng,
                draggable: true,
                raiseOnDrag: true,
                map: map,   
                labelContent: "<div class='arrow'></div><div class='inner'>998888</div>",
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 30),
                labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                isClicked: false
                });

                var windowDialog = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "<img height='180px' width='300px' src='images.car.jpg' />"
                            +"<h5>855555</h5>"  
                            +"Infor of dialog marker"
                            + "<br>"                                                                                        
                        });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(markerMap, "click", function (e) { windowDialog.open(map, this); });                                                                                  
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }       
            initMap();
```

How to fix this issue when hover on marker and show dialog highlight, thank so much !!

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle for your code

Comment: Hi @VinodLouis, I can provide anything, but I don't understand 'fiddle'

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ you can create a working sample of your code here because no one will get the value of `hanois`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a click listener in your code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerMap, "click", function (e) { 
               windowDialog.open(map, this);
 });
```

but for hover you should use mouseover and mouseout   eg using infowindow

```
markerMap.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});

// assuming you also want to hide the infowindow when user mouses-out
markerMap.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    infowindow.close();
});
```

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge: your mean is replace google.maps.event.addListener by google.maps.event.addListener

Comment: you should replace the click even with the mouseover and mouseout  event target